# character degree and solvability

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, characters

There is an unsolved problem in Berkovich's book "Characters of Finite Groups Part 2" I state here:

> Is $G$ solvable if $\chi(1)^2$ divides $|G|$ for all $\chi \in \operatorname{Irr}{(G)}$?

Can any one tell me some latest progresses for this? Maybe you can tell me some latest research papers. Thank you.

Comment: Problem 119 on page 303, for anyone who wants to look it up.

Comment: I do remember seeing this problem (though I think it was in a paper of Berkovich, rather than in the book). Unfortunately, as far as I am aware, none of those experts who work a lot with these sort of problems frequent MSE. I think Jack Schmidt is close, but his field of work is not quite this (as far as I know), and Alexander Gruber did some work recently with two of those experts, so we can hope those two see this (meaning Jack and Alexander). I have also worked on some similar problems myself, but not enough to be that familiar with the recent literature.

Comment: If you get no responses within 24 hours then you could try asking it on MathOverflow.

Comment: I would ask Marty Isaacs. Although he has retired as a professor from Madison, Wisconsin, he is still active on MathOverflow. See http://mathoverflow.net/users/9694/marty-isaacs. Or try to contact him directly.

Comment: Posted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/144192/character-degree-and-solvability

Answer (score 3):

Steve Gagola and I have a paper where we address this very question. I am away from home and so I don't have the reference handy. It was in the Communications in Algebra in the late 90's. I think 1998. Mark Lewis

Also, the example Marty gave was in that paper. Marty and I found that example while I was still working on my PhD.

Comment: Probably one of: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1649885 or http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1669104 -- the latter is most clearly relevant: if $\chi^2(1) | [G:\ker(\chi)]$ for all irred $\chi$, then $G$ is nilpotent.

Comment: Yes.  This is the correct paper.